# Discord gateway blocks for more than 10 seconds (But I don't know where in the code causes the block)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio, python-3.9

So, the bot seems like facing blocks on discord.gateway and here is the logging that I have for the blocking error. But except the line `asyncio.run(main())`, which is the required line to start the bot, there's nothing else pointing to my code showing what I did it incorrectly.
So I just wonder what I should do to solve this problem. 
Here is the logging:

```
2022-11-05 13:13:17,446:WARNING:discord.gateway: Shard ID None voice heartbeat blocked for more than 10 seconds
Loop thread traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Discord_Bot_Dev/Bot_Dev_Main.py", line 442, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 629, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 596, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1890, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/shard.py", line 164, in worker
    await self.ws.poll_event()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/gateway.py", line 623, in poll_event
    await self.received_message(msg.data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/gateway.py", line 573, in received_message
    func(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/state.py", line 612, in parse_message_create
    self.dispatch('message', message)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 220, in dispatch
    super().dispatch(event_name, *args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 467, in dispatch
    self._schedule_event(coro, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/discord/client.py", line 427, in _schedule_event
    return self.loop.create_task(wrapped, name=f'discord.py: {event_name}')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 433, in create_task
    task = tasks.Task(coro, loop=self, name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/_weakrefset.py", line 85, in add
    self.data.add(ref(item, self._remove))
```

Comment: Without seeing your code we can't really know what you're doing wrong either... It looks like one of your tasks, though. Do you have any tasks running that do non-async stuff?

Comment: *"I don't know what where in the code causes the block"*, how we gonna know? Guess your code?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I don't mean to let you guess my code. This is basically all I got for the blocking error. There's nothing else showing that which specific part that I did wrong but only show a line of starting the bot. And the bot starts with async. So which piece of code should I send? or should I send all 15 files of code? If I know which line causes the error, then why I don't post it because I want to let you guessing my code???

Comment: @stijndcl To be honest, the error lines didn't tell me which line that causes this error instead of a line which starts the bot. But I will definitely double-check the tasks and async stuff though I thought I put them in the loop_run_executor. Thanks a lot though.